# About the energy dependence of differencial cross section in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, scattering, scattering-cross-section

We know that the famous formula of differential transition probability per unit time (DTP) in QFT is written as:
$$
DTP= (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}(p_f-p_i)|A_{fi}|^2 \prod_{final} \frac{d^3 \mathbf{p}_f}{(2\pi)^32E_f}\prod_{initial} \frac{1}{2E_i}
$$
where $A_{fi}$ is the scattering amplitude.

I notice that there are $E_f$ and $E_i$ in the denominator, which means that the DTP is large as long as $E_f$ and $E_i$ are small (in general), and vice versa. This dependence on energy looks very strange to me, since there is no such energy dependence in non-relativistic scattering. Can someone give a reasonable explanation?